# How can I get my React component to render on exiting HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to insert a react component on an existing webpage. After reading the documentation I still can’t seem to get my react component  to render using JSX. Can someone explain what I am missing?

```
<!-- Some react code -->
<div id="welcome-back"></div>
<!-- Some react code -->


      <img class="shonprofile rounded-circle profilecenter " style="" src="images/shonblue2.png" alt="" width="300" height="300">


      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:10px">Submit</button>
   

   
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="src/Welcome.jsx" charset="utf-8"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

my component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react";



class WelcomeBack extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      name:'Tay',
      appVersion: ""
    };
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <h2>Hello{this.state.name || 'Friend'}!Welcome back</h2>
      <button>Download</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
let welcomeId = document.querySelector("#welcome-back");
ReactDOM.render(<WelcomeBack />, welcomeId);
```

Comment: import ReactDOM from "react"; try to replace 'react' with 'react-dom'

Answer (score 0):

As @lortschi pointed out in the comments...

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```